# Парсинг данных на Python

Tags: python, парсер

Всем добрый день. Как майские каникулы? Возник вопрос по поводу скрипта на Python. Пишу парсер, беру с сайта тексты, из текстов номер телефонов. Эти данные на сайте загружают раз в сутки, может 2. Это новостной сайт. Написал в коде:

```
import time
time.sleep(43200) # проверка раз в 12 часов на наличие новых текстов
```

данные (а именно номера телефонов из этих текстов) заношу в базу данных PostgreSQL. Нужно чтобы прога работала 24 часа в сутки. Запускаю прогу в пайчарме. Но ведь компьютер не может быть включен 24 часа в сутки. Но **как сделать, чтобы прога работала 24/7**, но и при этом заносила спарсенные данные в б?. Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, комп может работать 24/7 (когда я был студентом, он у меня по пол года не выключался). Во-вторых, никто не отменял аренду VDS/VPS/Виртуального хостинга(проще всего сразу настроенный виртуальный хостинг арендовать, но проверьте что бы там была возможность сменить php на python). Арендуете на хостинге VDS, устанавливаете туда питон, пишите функционал, заливаете его на VDS и настраиваете на ваш скрипт cron (планировщик задач, который присутствует практически на всех хостингах), который будет запускать ваш скрипт раз в 12 часов(а про time.sleep вообще забудьте тогда, в контексте этой задачи - это гавнокод) И будет вам счастье. Ну и базу данных тоже не забудьте на VDS перенести.

Comment: правильно, vps vds вирт в помощь!